# Using /index.php as a simple template and document router for a website?

Tags: php, templates

I need to put together a simple/small website fairly quickly for internal use (no external access), which will contain a few forms and simple interactive pages.

I don't really want the maintenance overhead of a CMS, but so that each page has a consistent look and feel, etc, it would be useful to be able to have each page be based on a common template to wrap around the unique page content, to include the HTML head, title, site navigation, footer, etc.

One approach would be to include various snippets via PHP within each individual page, but that involves repetition in each page, and doesn't scale well if I decide I might need to substantially change things later.

The alternative approach would be to use the main DocumentRoot index.php file as the template, and instead have it include the requested page 'within' itself (so that each of the other pages is actually really only a partial file defining variables for the 'title' and 'body' (for the main page body content)).

I see that I can use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` to extract the desired file path (relative to the DocumentRoot) and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the whole request string (in case there might be any `GET` parameters); for the actual content of the index page itself I could have it include an alternatively-named file instead; and there must be some way in Apache rewrite rules that it would be possible to elide out the index.php from the eventual URIs, ..but I haven't yet thought through very much further than this.

I am sure that this must be a scenario encountered many many times before. I could well spend a couple of days trying to think this through and re-invent my own wheel, but I don't really have the time to do this, and it probably wouldn't be a very good use of it in any case.

Does anybody have some existing "quickie" code that would be "good enough" for this, or know of something "formally" published (at which point does a working quick hack become an actual software package?!)?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: the MVC framework handles most of what you plan to achieve. if you're looking for something pretty barebone, you can try the MO framework... http://github.com/interwap/mo-framework

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, however, the webserver that I am using only has PHP 5.3. (Your Mo Framework says it needs PHP 5.6.)

Answer (score 0):

You could send your requested page as url parameter to your index.php, like 'index.php?page=requested_page' and include the following rule in your index.php at the position where you like to get your content

```
<?php
include("./pages/".$_GET['page'].".php");
?>
```

Comment: That was certainly something along the lines of my very initial thoughts, thanks. I was hoping that there might be an existing solution out there that is not substantially much more complicated, but is also robust (eg, prevents access to invalid pages, manages to use just the page path (and not as a GET request), etc).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if any effort you will put into this will be less than the effort of implementing a simple CMS. Most systems have simple setups and do most of the work for you. Any time you save on not implementing a CMS will cost you later on maintenance. Don't use 'internal use' as an excuse to make bad software. Unless it's a one-time solution that will be disregarded in a few weeks, you (or another developer) will have to extend and maintain the software.

Comment: You may well be right. Unfortunately, we have extremely limited resources and "good enough" is regarded as "good enough" (although this doesn't make me happy). I'm afraid I just don't have the time available to install and learn any sort of complicated new system at the present time. Our existing internal web system is very antiquated by current standards and has not yet reached the top of the list for replacing. The site I want to set up would be for reasonably limited and not too complicated purposes only until we can install a proper new CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect all requests to index:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php$|(?:css|js|media)(?:/|$)). index.php [L]
```

Something like that will stop redirect loops on the index and send everything except requests to static content folders (change to suit) to your handler in the index. Access the URL via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.